# More than one type under same ES index?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch version 6 and above , we can't create more than one type as explained at [Can't create two Types to same index elasticsearch & Kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632846/cant-create-two-types-to-same-index-elasticsearch-kibana).

My question is then what is the point of having type under index ?  Should not we have just index ?

Comment: Since this was a big change ES team decided to gradually take it out slowly. Mapping type has been restricted to one in es 6.x and removed in 7.x. Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types) for more information.

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204724/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch index types will still be partly deprecated in v7, but still exists as part of most APIs, for backward compatibility. in the next major version 8, it is going to be removed completely.

from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html

> Types will be deprecated in APIs in Elasticsearch 7.0.0, and completely removed in 8.0.0.