# Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters type nested in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, mapping, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

I’m trying to create an index in elasticsearch using kibana dev tools but i’m facing the following errors.please suggest me on this.

```
PUT xyz
{
“mappings”:{
“abc”:{
     “type”:”nested”,
     “properties”:{
         “name”:{“type”:”keyword”}
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Error:
    {
    type:”mapper_parsing_exception”,
    reason:”Root mapping definition has unsupported  parameters:[type:nested]
    }

It was working fine elasticsearch 7 but not in version 6.4.2

Answer (score 1):

This is because in ES 7, mapping types have been removed.
If you want to make this work on ES 6.4.2, you need to change your query to include a mapping type name, like this:

```
PUT xyz
{
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {                      <---- add this
      "properties": {                   <---- and this
        "abc": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,i was trying to make abc as mapping type in the index but not sure why it is not picking it,can u xplain why it is not picking as i’m following the same standards for index creation

Comment: as it stands, `abc` is a field name, not the mapping type name.

Comment: If i remove type :nested in my question ,abc is considered as mapping type ,if i include it is giving the above error

Comment: Because `nested` only works for fields, not types. Not sure what you want to do. It's working the same way in ES7

Comment: Thanks for the info ,really appreciate it and can u pls tell me whether can we create multiple mapping types under one index,if yes. Can u give me an example using same code.i tried it but couldn’t do it.thanks in advance

Comment: You should go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204579/elasticsearch-index-vs-type-and-handling-updates/45204724#45204724

Comment: Thanks for the link ,I have 15 nested types with each having 5 inner nested objects per document,i was thinking to create one index with 15 mapping types but couldn’t create it .do u suggest me to proceed with my approach in terms of scalable and performance by figuring out the problem OR creating 15 indeces would be tha appropriate one and a note is each document size varies but the structure would be the same.pls suggest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198144/discussion-between-ramesh-raj-and-val).

Comment: Having multiple types into a single index is clearly not the way to go anymore (won't be allowed anymore as of ES 7 onwards). You definitely need to create as many indexes as types you have... or since they have very similar structures, a single index with a `type` field that allows you to discriminate each type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,i’m trying to create single index but as i have 68 nested fields per document it is giving me an error like limit of nested fields 50 in index has been exceeded.can u suggest me how do i resolve this

Comment: The limit of 50 nested fields per index can be lifted [as explained here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_limits_on_nested_mappings_and_objects)

Comment: Got it ,i’m able to create the index now but will it effect the performance of search functionality  for changing the nested field limit and i’m trying to search thru kibana by applying the filter on the field of the index but becoz of nested it is returning empty result. Can u pls suggest on this .thanks in advance:)

Comment: The Discover view in Kibana doesn't work with nested data (yet). You can only query it through Dev Tools

Comment: Is there any other UI based search tool other than kibana supports nested data based search queries.by d way may i know the performance impact for changing nested field limit